# 1D CNN in Keras: if the number of filters and kernel_size are too low, will it stop convolution at the middle of a sequence?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

For example, I have a sequence of length 100, and I want to use `Conv1D` in Keras to do convolution:

If I set the number of `filters = 10` and `kernel_size = 4`, from my understanding, I will have **10  windows** where **every window has a size of 4**.

Since **10 x 4 = 40 which is less than 100**, I wonder how will the window distribute along the sequence.

Will the convolution stop at the middle without scanning through the whole sequence?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each filter (a window with size of 4) will be swept over input (96 different position). look at the image below:

[image]

you have 10 red-window-like filters, each works independently (red window is just one filter). So this way you'll have 10 output each with size of 96 (or an output with shape of (10,96)). If you understand this picture, then go and learn what is **stride** and **padding**